# how to select values from date-picker in Cucumber-java

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, cucumber-jvm

I am trying a scenario to book a flight on Expedia website.but unable to select a departure date from the date picker view.i am able to enter the date by using submit keys.but i want it to auto selected by a click.
kindly help me out of this.following is my code

```
@When("^I click on Departing date$")
public void I_click_on_Departing_date() throws Throwable {
   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='flight-departing']")).sendKeys("26/07/2015");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution for my own question and it worked..
By Adding below Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='flight-departing']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='home-page']/div[16]/div/div/section[1]/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add .click() at the end like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='flight-departing']")).sendKeys("26/07/2015").click();
```

Comment: Hi oliver,thanks for replying but the solution you have suggested is not by problem. i am able to execute above code without including click().i just want to capture the date from date picker.